# Toggle visibility of three or more divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple script that toggles the visability of two divs:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(window).load(function(){
        function toggle_contents() {
            $('#page1').toggle();
            $('#page2').toggle();
            setTimeout(function(){
                toggle_contents()
            }, 25000)
        }
        toggle_contents();
    });
</script>

<div id="container">
    <div id="page1">This is page 1 contents.</div>
    <div id="page2" style="display:none;">This is page 2 contents.</div>
</div>
```

It works great but I can not figure out how to add more divs to the mix.

http://jsfiddle.net/mxwv85px/1/

Any help is much appreciated...

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking....

Comment: IO want to be able to add more divs to the mix.

    <div id="page3" style="display:none;">This is page 3 contents.</div>   

    <div id="page4" style="display:none;">This is page 4 contents.</div>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To cycle through a set of divs you could use a class on the active `div`, and use `next` to move on each iteration. Something like this:

```
function toggle_contents() {
    var $active = $('#container .active');
    if ($active.length && $active.next().length) {
        $active.hide().removeClass('active').next().show().addClass('active');
    }
    else {
        $('.active').hide();
        $('#container div:first').show().addClass('active');
    }

    setTimeout(toggle_contents, 3000)
}
toggle_contents();
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mxwv85px/8/)

Comment: This looks exactly like what I want to do.  I am going to try and implement it now.

Comment: Rory,
  Is it possible to set the timeout for each div so some can be displayed longer than others?

Answer (score 2):

.toggle() means the div's are toggled between hidden and displayed. I would suggest using .hide() and .show() instead, as this gives you more control about what content you want to display or not. However, the downside is you would need a code that has much more lines to it. Give me a second while I try to make such a thing for you.

Currently you can only have 2 divs, because the .toggle() function can only have 2 values, which means a third div will have the same value as another div, causing it to be either visible or hidden while another div is as well.

The code provided in this answer by @Rory McCrossan is already working, so I'll stop trying to program it myself:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27447139/4274852

Comment: Thank you Kevin.  I appreciate any help!  I am new to all of this and trying to teach myself!

Comment: I have to do this all the time to things, Kevin's right, but I'd go a step further.  Give all of the type a class, then you $(".class").hide, $(".id").show();  This will cut out a lot of those lines, and make it easier to add or remove pages later (reusable code).

Comment: I added a link to the code provided by Rory McCrossan in this answer as it works like intended: credits given ;)

Comment: `.toggle()` is *not wrong*, just more difficult to read. If you replace all occurences of `show` and `hide` in Rory's answer with `toggle`, it will still work; but it will also look uglier. All you need to make it work is a handle to the target.

Comment: @blgt It will not do what the asker wanted though: You will still have the same problem.

Comment: @KevinVoorn I'm pretty sure it will, just needs an initial `.active`: http://jsfiddle.net/mxwv85px/17/

Answer (score 1):

You could cycle through the selected elements and show only one each call

```
var page=0;
function toggle_contents() {
    $('.page').hide();
    var array = $('.page').toArray();
    $(array[page]).show(); 
    page=++page%array.length;
    setTimeout(function(){toggle_contents()}, 3000)
}
toggle_contents();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mxwv85px/9/

Answer (score 1):

You can do this

http://jsfiddle.net/mxwv85px/13/

The code

```
<div id="container">
<div id="page1">This is page 1 contents.</div>
<div id="page2" style="display:none;">This is page 2 contents.</div>
<div id="page3" style="display:none;">This is page 3 contents.</div>
<div id="page4" style="display:none;">This is page 4 contents.</div>
<div id="page5" style="display:none;">This is page 5 contents.</div>
```

```
function toggle_contents() {
var items = $('#container div');

for(var i= 0; i < items.length; i++)
{
    if($(items[i]).is(":visible")) {
        $(items[i]).hide();
        i + 1 == items.length ? $(items[0]).show() : $(items[i+1]).show();
        break;
    }        

}

setTimeout(function(){ toggle_contents() }, 500)
}

toggle_contents();
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, put timer out of toggle_contents function. Secondly, add to divs common class, cache them and operate with variable-cache

```js
$(window).load(function(){
  var divs = $('.some-class');
  function toggle_contents() {
    divs.toggle();
  }
  setTimeout(function(){
    toggle_contents()
  }, 25000)

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="some-class">
  
</div>

<div class="some-class">
  
</div>

<div class="some-class">
  
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

To add more divs, you can use .append, for example:

```
$('#container').append('<div id="page3">This is page 3 contents</div>');
```

Comment: why the minus 2? From the OP he clearly states he wants to add more divs: "It works great but I can not figure out how to add more divs to the mix."

Comment: nevermind--I see I misunderstood what he meant by 'add more divs'